# Packaging a WAR file in an EAR so that WAR dependencies are available

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, packaging, war, ear

I am adding a WAR module [my-web-app] to an existing EAR application [my-ear-app] that currently contains EJB modules only. The WAR module is a RESTful app written in Spring MVC 3.0.
The apps are maven 2.x apps.
When I run the EAR app on WebLogic 10.3.2 it fails to publish the WAR module that I added.
I am running this in WebLogic 10.3.2 from Eclipse Helios.
I have tried the app fuse warpath config in the pom but that didn't work. I also looked at the skinny wars approach. I added links to this relevant material at end of the post.

I can't seem to get past the missing oxm lib error - NoClassDefFoundError:org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller.

The error happens when an attempt is made to publish the EAR app to the WL app server.

The published EAR deploys as:

- META-INF\application.xml
- META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
- META-INF\weblogic-application.xml
- my-web-app.war
- .beabuild.txt

The published WAR module from the EAR extracts as:

- WEB-INF\lib\jstl-1.2.jar
- WEB-INF\lib\spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

For comparison, the maven packaged WAR from the web app extracts as:

- META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF\classes
- WEB-INF\jsp
- WEB-INF\lib (has all WAR dependencies)
- WEB-INF\spring
- web.xml

This is a partial error trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper$DeploymentProgressListener.watch(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1559)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy (WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:484)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules (WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1419)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer    (WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:861)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce (WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:655)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish (WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish (ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:2888)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "mywebapp" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "mywebapp". java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:389)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1836)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determinCCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInsance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactor.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext (FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext (FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext (FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean (FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run (StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet (StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance (StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:531)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet (WebAppServletContext.java:1915)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup (WebAppServletContext.java:1889)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources (WebAppServletContext.java:1807)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3045)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1397)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next (ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start (ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start (ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start (ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next (ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start (ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate (StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:54)
...
```

Below is the WAR module's org.eclipse.wst.common.component file, it has two EJB dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="my-web-app">       
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/java"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/test/java"/>
    <dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/ejb-module-1/ejb-module1">
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
    </dependent-module>
    <dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/resource/ejb-module-2/ejb-module2">
        <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
    </dependent-module>
<property name="java-output-path" value="/my-web-app/target/classes"/>
    <property name="context-root" value="my-web-app"/>
</wb-module>
```

Below is the EAR module's org.eclipse.wst.common.component file. The EAR module has the web module dependency as well as many EJB dependencies. The EAR org.eclipse.wst.common.component file shows only two EJB dependencies to make it easier to read. The first EJB dependency type is EJB modules at the project root level and the second EJB dependency type is EJB modules written to the lib/ folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0"> 
        <wb-module deploy-name="my-ejb-module"> 
            <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/EarContent"/> 
            <dependent-module archiveName="ejb-module-A.jar" deploy-path="/"   handle="module:/resource/ejbmoduleA/ejbmoduleA"> 
                <dependent-object/> 
                <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type> 
            </dependent-module> 
            <dependent-module archiveName="ejb-module-B-SNAPSHOT.jar" deploy-path="/lib" handle="module:/resource/ejb-module-B-SNAPSHOT/ejb-module-B-SNAPSHOT">
                <dependent-object/> 
                <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type> 
             </dependent-module> 
            <dependent-module archiveName="my-web-app.war" deploy-path="/" handle="module:/resource/my-web-app/my-web-app"> 
                <dependent-object/> 
                <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
             </dependent-module> 
     </wb-module>
```

Below is the pom.xml file for the EAR app:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">   

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ear.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-ear-app</artifactId> 
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

</properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-W</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-X</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>        
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-Y</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-Z</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.web.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-web-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
<build>
    <plugins>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
            <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
                <earSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/application</earSourceDirectory>
                <earSourceIncludes>META-INF/**</earSourceIncludes>
                <defaultJavaBundleDir>APP-INF/lib</defaultJavaBundleDir>
                <version>5</version>
                <modules>                                           <jarModule> 
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                    
                    </jarModule>    
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module-M</artifactId>                           
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>            
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module-N</artifactId>                           
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>            
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module-O</artifactId>                           
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module-P</artifactId>                               
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>castor-core</artifactId>                
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
                        <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>             
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>             
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>        
                        <includeInApplicationXml>false</includeInApplicationXml>                        
                    </jarModule>            
                </modules>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
    <finalName>MY EAR APP</finalName>
</build>
```

This is the web module's pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.web.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-web-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   
<packaging>war</packaging>

</properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-1</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ejb.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-module-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

References:

1. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Solving+the+Skinny+Wars+problem
2. [Maven WAR dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency)
   This one is similar to my problem and I attempted to use it to solve my issue but to no avail. It has an example of using warpath from appfuse.

Comment: @R. Bemrose thanks for the editing

Comment: I am still stumped by this so am retracing changes I made to the EAR app when adding the WAR. First I right click on project in Eclipse Helios and select Properties -> Deployment Assembly and then I select Add... -> Project and from the list of projects displayed in the Add a Project Reference dialog I select my-web-app project. Then I add the WAR project dependency to the pom. I still get same missing oxm.Marshaller error.

Comment: If I add the oxm dependency to an EJB module all is ok. So trying to work out how to add it to WAR and have dependency picked up by EAR deploy. I am back looking at skinny WARs stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller is not part of spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar. I'm not familiar with webmvc or its dependencies, but perhaps spring-oxm-x.y.z.jar is one of its deps and thus needs to be included in WEB-INF/lib?

Regards,
 DagR.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think the issue is that the WAR's dependencies don't get published when the EAR is deployed to the server. Your answer has prompted me to add the relevant pom files and the detail of what the structure of the deployed WAR should look like to the question. The question was really incomplete without them. Please review these if you can and maybe you can then see what the issue is. Thanks!

Comment: As @DagR alludes to in his answer the issue is more straight forward that I was framing it. It was merely a case of the EAR packaging missing the spring-oxm jar. I added this and it worked. However I still have an issue namely that I can add the missing jar to one of the dependent EJB modules and all is good but when I add it to either the web module's pom or the EAR's pom it doesn't get picked up. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: The problem was with the Sonatype maven eclipse plugin. The plugin failed to deploy the dependencies for the web project. Deploying to the target weblogic server using a script worked ok. I switched to eclipse jee 3.6.2 and the deploy worked fine.