# Maven - Generate Jar and War

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, cxf, maven-plugin

I have a CXF WS project that I would use it in another project, I would consume this WS in a Web Project but I don't know how to generate Jar file.

Please have you any idea or an example?

Thank you

Comment: Similar question: [Maven WAR dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769586/873282)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The maven-war-plugin supports creating a separate artifact that just contains the classes.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

See the 'attachClasses' parameter. No need to add in the jar plugin or mess with the packaging. Just add the war plugin to pluginManagement and turn this on.

However, I fear this this isn't what you want. To consume a CXF web service, you need a client. To get a client, follow the instructions in the CXF samples for how to generate and use client stubs. You'll want a separate maven project for this.

Comment: this is nice but the addition `<classifier>classes</classifier>` is unusual these days

Comment: Do note that an Eclipse bug prevents snapshots from being updated properly. Instead of doing `Update project -> Update snapshots/releases`, run `mvn clean install -U`.
See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502349

Comment: there is a standard way using a configuration parameter '<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>' you may use with the WAR plugin

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached

Answer (score 28):

Try adding this into your build section:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-a-jar</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It seems that I have to change phase to package. If it is set to compile, there is a error on pom.xml.

Comment: This worked, but how would you include this *.jar produced by the maven-jar-plugin inside a war package built by the maven-war-plugin?

Answer (score 24):

Add following to pom.xml of war project.

`<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` to configuration of war plugin

```
<groupId>com.yourorg.foobar</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>hello</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Add following to pom.xml of the project where you want to import jar of war project

`<classifier>classes</classifier>` to dependency import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yourorg.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is there a way to change the jar file's name?

Comment: It generates .java files. I need compiled .class files. How can I do it?

Answer (score 14):

This is a one way to achieve it, via property.
By default it will generate a war file, and when you want the jar just set the property.

```
mvn install -Dp.type=jar
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
   <p.type>war</p.type>
</properties>
<packaging>${p.type}</packaging>
```

Comment: worked for me. only thing is I replaced p.type with p-type as got errors: unknown lifecycle phase ".type=jar"

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
<!-- Maven JAR plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-services-provided</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- Install the jar locally -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <file>
                    ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
                </file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Taken from [this blog](http://communitygrids.blogspot.co.at/2007/11/maven-making-war-and-jar-at-same-time.html).

Answer (score 4):

Considering your maven project packaging to war

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

add the following executions to maven-install-plugin

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <file>${project.build.directory}\${artifactId}-${version}.jar</file>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I wanted to generate a war, but just got a .jar instead, but adding <packaging>war</packaging> as you suggested above helps! Thanks

Comment: In this case maven-install-plugin create/install also a jar file. The war file is created using maven-war-plugin

Answer (score 2):

`mvn package` unless your [project's packaging](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) is something besides `jar`. Then you'd need to [add an execution](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html#configuring-sect-exec-param) of the [jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), as described on the [plugin's usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) and as the first answer showed. Better yet, if it's not a jar, divide it into two modules: one that's a jar containing your reusable code, and the other the thing that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by using Maven assembly plugin by this you can also control the final name of the jar :

Add the following plugin in your pom.xml :

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

assembly.xml :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>model</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

You can finally build the project with the command below:

mvn clean package assembly:single install