# Adding a war dependency with appassembler-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am using appassembler-maven-plugin to create the script to run an application. That application depends on several projects and solves this dependencies using Maven. One of the project is packeged as a war.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.war.dependency</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem I have is that the appassembler is not extracting the war dependency, only the jar dependencies. So I cannot refer to the classes in this war in order to create the script calling to one of the classes inside.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency

Comment: Can you show the full configuration for appassembler-maven-plugin and how you call maven etc.