# maven: Adding classes in war/web-inf/classes as dependency to a Jar module

Tags: java, spring, maven

The task is to create customization to the core project. The core project can not be modified by my team.

The requirement is to change the control flow to the core and implement controller and services extending or using the core classes. Here the customization will be delivered as Jar and Core product will be war. That means the classes that i am going to extend are in web-inf/classes folder of a war. Both customization and core product uses maven.

The problem I am facing here is that, I am not sure how to add war as dependency to my jar (customization)

Any thought please. Also please let me know if there is a good design to do.

Comment: If you are going to separate out your code into a jar which is going to be placed in a war. The jar should not extend any classes of the war but the war can or cannot(makes it more like a pluggable jar).

Comment: this makes no sense, generally core stuff are jars (like springs) and people use them, extend them in their war

Comment: This is not a good design. Place the dependent classes in a separate `core classes` project and include as a dependency for the `core war` project. Then you can extend your core classes as needed. Note however, that if the customization should go into the `core war` again the war should be at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Is this former question about Maven war dependencies relevant to your current question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency

Comment: sorry, i was on a vacation so could not reply to post. @Chris Nauroth , yes, i was looking for a similar thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not for your case - but solved my problems,  you can create a separate jar from the war,  that will contain only classes

https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/using-a-war-module-as-dependency-in-maven/

```
<build>
...
  <plugins>
  ...
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
      <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
...
</build>
```

produces xxx.war and xxx.classes.jar that you can include

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.pascalalma.adapters</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-adapter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.