# How can I add war file to another java web application dependencies?

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-plugin

I have web maven project. Project's output is a `war` file. I want to add this `war` file as dependency to project_b.
The project_b's `pom.xml` file, have a plugin as following:

```
...
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>geoserver</warName>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/geoserver</webappDirectory>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <GeoServerModule>core</GeoServerModule>
                <Application-Name>${project.build.finalname}</Application-Name>
                <Project-Version>${project.version}</Project-Version>
                <Iteration-Name>${iteration}</Iteration-Name>
                <Build-Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Timestamp>
                <Git-Revision>${build.commit.id}</Git-Revision>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

How do I add the `war` of  web application to project_b with `<groupId>org.itsme</groupId>`, `<artifactId>spring3-mvc-maven-xml-hello-world</artifactId>`, `<packaging>war</packaging>` and `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`?

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency

Comment: I suppose extract common logic into separate java module and add it as jar-dependency to both destinations is better way.

Comment: I want to add some html page to the project

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Maven, adding dependency is just a piece of cake. Take a look on the following pom.xml.

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Project Details -->
    <groupId>ykyuen</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-apple</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>project-apple</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- project-apple depends on project-banana -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ykyuen</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-banana</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Setting the above dependency is just the same as importing the project-banana.jar in project-apple.

Now i have another Maven web application project called project-orange with packaging type equals to war. Adding the above dependency linkage does not work at all since Java does not see .war file as a classpath.

**To solve the problem, there are two approaches:**

1. Create a Maven module which contains the classes of project-orange with jar packaging. Now you can treat the new Maven module as normal dependency.
2. Configure the maven-war-plugin such that it will build the .jar file when building the .war file. Add the following code under the  node of your war project. The following is an example.

.

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

After running mvn install, you can find the following archive files in the target folder

- project-orange.war
- project-orange-classes.jar

Now you can edit the pom.xml of project-apple for adding the new dependency.

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Project Details -->
    <groupId>ykyuen</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-apple</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>project-apple</name>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- project-apple depends on project-banana -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ykyuen</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-banana</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- project-apple depends on project-orange -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ykyuen</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-orange</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!-- To map the project-orange-classes.jar -->
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**reference**: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/10/30/maven-dependency-on-jarwar-package/

Answer (score 6):

Recently, I was also facing the same problem. This is how I solved it very simply.

**Step 1:** In the pom of original project(Not dependent on any project)Configure the maven war plugin in such a way that it will build war as well as jar. The jar will be uploaded into the maven repository when we do mvn clean install.

*My first part of pom looked like this:*

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pancharatna</groupId>
<artifactId>TestWebApp</artifactId>
**<packaging>jar</packaging>**
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

*Next, add another plugin in the build section:*

```
<build>
    <finalName>TestWebApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        **<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-a-war</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>**

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Step 2:** In the 2nd project(which is dependent on the first project), put the dependency jar(Original Project)in the pom.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pancharatna</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestWebApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Step 3:**  Do mvn clean install for the project and then for the second project

**Step 4:** Optional : Instead of building the projects sequentially and separately as mentioned in Step 3, we can create a parent pom. 
We can simple run mvn clean install.:

```
C:/Test/
        ├───Project1
        │   └───src/main/...
        │   └───pom.xml
        │
        ├───Project2
        │   └───src/main/...
        │   └───pom.xml
        │
        ├───pom.xml   <!-- parent pom -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>/Project1</module>
        <module>/Project2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: How can i achieve this using gradle?