# Maven pom.xml local dependency not Resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven

Using `eclipse` `maven` and `java 1.7` I have designed two backends named `webservice.staff.backend` **and**  `webservice.webuser.backend` .

Now There is another `webservice` which is written by  some of our **Senior Team Member**, which is a another module for Project shared with me by `git`.

> In this New Project in `pom.xml` there are two **local project dependency** have been added as Follows.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>webservice.staff.backend</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservice.staff.backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
        <type>jar</type>   //used jar but webservices packaging as a war
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>webservice.webuser.backend</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservice.webuser.backend</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
        <type>jar</type> // used jar but webservices packaging as a war
    </dependency>
```

but these dependency is not resolved when I am just trying to perform **Maven** `clean` `install`. What I Found in my earlier `webservice` Projects are packaging as a `WAR` but here used as `jar`

> Here is earlier Project packaging type in `pom.xml`.

```
<groupId>webservice.staff.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice.staff.backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging> //packaged as war but used as jar??

<groupId>webservice.webuser.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice.webuser.backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>  //packaged as war but used as jar in

    /*I Have also Changed packaging as a jar and then clean Install 
      and try to build the New Project but error still the same. */
```

### Error StackTrace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webservice.credit.backend: Could not resolve dependencies for project webservice.credit.backend:webservice.credit.backend:war:2.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: webservice.staff.webservice.staff.backend:jar:classes:1.0.0, webservice.webuser.backend:webservice.webuser.backend:jar:classes:1.0.0: Failure to find webservice.staff.backend:webservice.staff.backend:jar:classes:1.0.0 in http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Java.Net has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

> **Note** :- I have tried so many ways and also so many answers on `stackOverflow`in this regard but no one gives me correct solution to that.

Please Help anybody to Resolve this.. Thanks.

Comment: follow all steps and check if you are getting any issue after that : http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html?page=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020038/how-can-i-add-war-file-to-another-java-web-application-dependencies , this one can help too

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this too at earlier @DipaliVasani

Comment: as you may see version 2.0.0 is for Investor backend  not for `staff` and `web-User` backend actually . Dependency is added with `1.0.0` for `staff` and `web-user`

Comment: check your settings.xml for <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>

Comment: @DipaliVasani.. Please Read the question again.. I thing u didn't get my Context. bydway I have already checked my `.m2` Directory and ` jar `and `war` both is Present. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally**  !!!
 Got the solution for this.

what i need to do during `clean` & `install` add extra `param` with `mvn` to export the class files. parameter ==> `-Dattach.and.archive.classes=true` to the `mvn` command.

```
mvn clean install -Dattach.and.archive.classes=true //added one extra param
   // -Dattach.and.archive.classes=true solved my dependency Problem.
```

> **Note** :- If you Defined in `pom.xml` Project packaging as `war` and want a `jar` as dependency in Your local `maven` Repository. Just put this extra Option with `-Dattach.and.archive.classes=true` with `mvn`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<classifier>classes</classifier>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>webservice.staff.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice.staff.backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>webservice.webuser.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice.webuser.backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

pom will be same for both projects except packaging will be jar :

```
<groupId>webservice.staff.backend</groupId>
<artifactId>webservice.staff.backend</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<groupId>webservice.webuser.backend</groupId>
<artifactId>webservice.webuser.backend</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Make sure your settings.xml is like below :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  ------
</settings>
```

I have uploaded sample [here](http://tinyurl.com/hf4q96x).

Comment: I got the solution and I mentioned my solution here. I Have no time to do a R&D so, I will check out your solution as soon as i will  have a free time ..

Thanks.. Again For your effort.. :)

Comment: I am not using `setting.xml` File Actually.. but thanks Again.. For Your Effort.