# Adding a local Maven project as a dependency in another local Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a local java application that I have recently converted to a Maven project. My goal is to add my recently converted maven project to another Maven project as a dependency in Eclipse STS.

The temporary path of the recently converted maven project is C:\Users\nconnor2\Desktop and the path of the soon-to-be parent Maven project is C:\Users\nconnor2\Desktop\adoudrepo.

I'm really struglling to wrap my head around how maven works when dealing with local maven project.

The pom of my new maven project is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TB2TUBSync</groupId>
  <artifactId>TB2TUBSync</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</project>
```

The pom of my soon-to-be parent Maven project is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bellmts</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <name>TB2TUBSyncWeb</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

What I have been trying to do is to include my new maven project as a module in my soon-to-be parent maven project but I get an error that I can't include a module in another maven project with war packaging.

At the end of the day I need to access methods from TB2TUBSync (new maven) in TB2TUBSyncWeb (soon-to-be parent maven).

Comment: Those are snippets of POMs, right? You're tailing the first and truncating the second.

Comment: @ingyhere they are, I just added the full contents of the first Pom, the second Pom is very lengthy. I don’t think the remainder of the Pom will be relevant to this question so I truncated the content of the POm to keep my question brief.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090564/325452

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31220514/325452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to leverage the [WAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) to generate both JARs and the WAR file, then you can publish the jars to your local repository with `mvn clean install`. At that point you can import them into the other POM with dependency resolution.

It's detailed at https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/10/30/maven-dependency-on-jarwar-package/ .