# How to add a war file as a maven dependency in pom.xml file

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a project with 2 packages in it. I have a war file present in 1st package. I want to make use of this war file in package 2. How can I add maven dependency in package 2 pom.xml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven WAR dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency)

Comment: What  have you tried yet?

Answer (score 5):

In general `war` package usually don't make sense to use them as dependencies. But you can create separate `jar` packages of the classes (incl. resources) which are in the `war` project. This can be achieved by using the following in your 1st package:

```xml
<project>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

So this create a supplemental `jar` file with the following coordinates `groupId:artifactId:classifier:version` in this case `groupId:artifactId:classes:version` which you now can use as a dependency in your 2nd project.