# Import from war file

Tags: java, import, war

I want to use a class defined in external war file. I've put it into dependency list of my `pom.xml`, specifying `<type>war</type>` as well. However, during the compilation of the source code it does not find the import, I receive `cannot find symbol` error message. Does anyone know how to use classes defined in an external war?

Comment: I think this is what you need :  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769586/maven-war-dependency

Comment: Thank you for your comments; the second one helped! Please add it as an answer and I accept as solution.